# Get menu index with regex fails with python, works online

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract a menu index with python. The menu index is a tree like this:

```
1.
1.1.
1.1.1.
2.
3.1.
3.2.
```

To find this I wrote the following code:

```
first = re.findall(r"[0-9]{1}[.]{1}(?:([0-9][.])?(?:([0-9]?[.]?)))" , menu)
```

This doesn't work, but when I put the regex in the online regex tool (http://www.regexr.com/) then it works.

How is this possible?

Comment: Whats your expected output?

Comment: Which number(s) do you want to extract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually reduce the regex a lot as

```
re.findall(r"[0-9]\.(?:[0-9]\.){,2}" , menu)
```

**What it does?**

- `[0-9]` matches digits. I have dropped `{1}` because that is trivial as this pattern matches a single character.
- `\.` Matches `.`, escaped the special meaning.
- `(?:[0-9]\.){,2}` Matches digits followed by `.` for minimum of zero times and maximum of `2` times.

**Test**

```
>>> string = """1.
... 1.1.
... 1.1.1.
... 2.
... 3.1.
... 3.2."""
>>> re.findall(r"[0-9]\.(?:[0-9]\.){,2}" , string)
['1.', '1.1.', '1.1.1.', '2.', '3.1.', '3.2.']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[0-9][.](?:(?:[0-9][.])?(?:(?:[0-9]?[.]?)))
```

You need to make all `capturing groups` `non capturing`.`re.findall` gives a list of all `groups` if there are any present.You have `2` groups so you might be getting only those.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hI0qP0/5

You can also use `(?:[0-9][.])+` or `(?:[0-9][.]){1,3}`.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hI0qP0/6

Answer (score 1):

It might be more prudent to allow any number of digits for chapters and sections (ie, there may be more than 10 chapters or more than 10 items/subitems). In that case, you could use just

`(\d+)\.`

This regex finds numbers before periods and matches the numbers; thus you would have, for a single line:

```
>>> re.findall(r"(\d+)\." , "3.2.1.")
['3', '2', '1']
```

If you apply the regex to the whole string, you would get all the numbers in sequence; ie, for your string, `['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '3', '1', '3', '2', '3']`. I didn't quite understand which data you want to match or what you want to do with it, so, well, tweak to taste. :-)

To get a list with the numbers in your index, you could use:

```
>>> [re.findall(r"(\d+)", i) for i in string.split('\n')]
[['1'], ['1', '1'], ['1', '1', '1'], ['2'], ['3', '1'], ['3', '2'], ['3', '3']]
```

Cheers,
 Paulo